# Which font-family spec do you use that looks great on mac AND windows?

Tags: css, fonts

Arial on windows looks bad, but on mac it's cool. What font-family set do you use in your website do help both mac and windows with a nice looking font?

Comment: Asking a bunch of programmers about typography... :-P

Answer (score 3):

Verdana...

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is not which font to choose, but the ways Microsoft and Apple have decided to render them on a computer screen. Microsoft focuses on readability on screen, with high contrasts but less accuracy, whereas Apple put emphasis on typography accuracy with some blurr on subpixel rendering.

Joel Spolsky has an article on this subject: [Font smoothing, anti-aliasing, and sub-pixel rendering](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/06/12.html)

Comment: +1, anti-aliasing is the difference the OP is getting. It may be worse than in Spolsky's example since anti-aliasing may even be completely turned off in Windows. But there's nothing a web author can do to interfere with AA settings.

Answer (score 2):

Trebuchet, is another good.

Answer (score 1):

`sans-serif` :)

Answer (score 1):

Georgia works well for both headings and body text.

Comment: I love it too. Was scared, because thinking not many people think that. +1

Comment: For a good example of combining it with Lucida Grande, check out http://simplebits.com/